# pass image url as string to another component e

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-props

I want to pass "getImageURL()" props in the card-product component but the problem I've to render images using computed function so how can I use the image in card-prdouct component

```
  
      <img bind:src="getImageURL()" v-on="on" />
      <card-product  :image="getImageURL()"> </card-popup>
</template>

<script>


export default {

  
    getImageURL: function() {
      const image_name = this.product.image_url;
      if (image_name == "") {
        return "/static/img/Product.png";
      } else {
        return `${IMAGE_URL}${image_name}`;
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: this should actually work...in your card component you can just use ..........
<img :src="image" />

Comment: I had tried this but not work

Comment: If this is not working then try defining a data property and then set its value through the computed property and pass that data property in the prop, then I think it should work.